# PHP - sending a complete row with one checkbox and POST

Tags: php, mysql, post, checkbox

I have a table with rows that are in the form:
ID, Name, First Name, IntA, IntB, IntC, ...
The last columns are textfields.

I want to select multiple rows with a Checkbox and send the ID and the recorded integers with POST to another PHP-File.

This is my code-example (with a little bit German in it):

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='auswahl[]' value='$daten[0]'></td>";
echo "<td>" . $daten['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='number' name='Schr' value='".$punkte['PktSchr']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='number' name='Mdl' value='".$punkte['PktMdl']."'></td>";
```

So in the other PHP-File I want to SQL for all checked rows like this (in a Loop):

```
$Eintraege  = $_POST['auswahl'];
$Schr       = $_POST['Schr'];
$Mdl        = $_POST['Mdl'];
foreach ($Eintraege as $i){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO aufnahme (IDSchueler, PktSchr, PktMdl) Values ('$i', '$Schr', '$Mdl')";
}
```

My problem is this: `$Eintraege` contains only the IDs of the selected rows (because of `value='$daten[0]'`).
`$Schr` and `$Mdl` contains the values of the textfields of the last row (doesn't matter, which rows are selected).

So I tried to set `value='$daten'` and use it like an array, but then I get an Exception.

I think I have to change `value='$daten[0]'`, but don't know how.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use an array for the `name` attribute like you already do for `auswahl[]`. And you should read up on sql injection.

Comment: Thx, i definitely do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ***two other names*** to ***array type*** too and you will get all values.

So do like below:-

```
echo "<td><input type='number' name='Schr[]' value='".$punkte['PktSchr']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='number' name='Mdl[]' value='".$punkte['PktMdl']."'></td>";
```

And then you can do like below:-

```
foreach ($Eintraege as $k=> $i){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO aufnahme (IDSchueler, PktSchr, PktMdl) Values ('$i', '$Schr[$k]', '$Mdl[$k]')";
}
```

Comment: Thx, works perfectly. :)
But I don't get, what $k => $i is doing. Can you please tell me?

Comment: $k is the keys from first array. these keys are used to fetch exact same record from other two arrays. this is also called array indexes. So it used to fetch values from all three arrays (same indexes)

Answer (score 1):

As @Alive-to-Die mentioned, turn the names into arrays.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='auswahl[]' value='$daten[0]'>
```

This itself doesn't look good. Consider making it

```
<input type='checkbox' name='auswahl[]' value='{$daten[0]}'>
```

or

```
<input type='checkbox' name='auswahl[]' value='".$daten[0]."'>
```

These are two proper ways to use variables inside strings.

Comment: Can you tell me, why the curly brackets in value='{$daten[0]}? Thx!

Comment: It's the way to put variables inside strings marked with double quotes. So if you have $var = "this text goes to show {$var2} here"; it will work. If you have single quotes, it will print not the variable but {$var2} as text. Read about the different between single and double quotes, its good to understand it early.